# MVC pattern and write files to disk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Could anyone tell me which component in MVC pattern is responsible for writing files to disk? Is this a controller or model? Some links or examples would be appreciated(especially for ASP.NET MVC, but not necessarily :)

Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi=)
Model must be responsible for persistence.

If you use database -> try with Repository pattern.

If you need to save files on disk directly -> just create something like "MyFileSavingService" end encapsulate whole logic of saving file to disk in it.

And then, from your controller just call `MyFileDavingService.SaveSomthingToSomewhere(bla,blabla);`